# Wheather Android studio proxy is prefered over system proxy specifically when no proxy opt is in AS

Tags: android, gradle

Need to you about internet traffic flow if no proxy is set in Android studio and there proxy configure at system level then how it could try to reach internet in case any repository that required to be download. Is there any change that it will try to get through internet via system proxy or try to go out directly neglecting system configured proxy

To understand exact traffic flow of internet related query made by AS if no proxy opt is available.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Traffic flow from AS app when no proxy configured in it